# Dynamically add checkboxes and event handler to a worksheet

Tags: vba, dynamic, event-handling, worksheet

In my sheet in column B I have names of components
In column A I would like to have checkboxes which are dynamically added, as the list of names in column B will increase over time

I need to be able to do the following:
- handle the events (onclick) as ticking/unticking the checkboxes hides/unhides rows in another sheet
- return the status of each checkbox as I cycle through the checkboxes in another module (onclick from a commandbox) and depending on the status an action follows or not
- modify the status of each checkbox as I have 1 commandbox to tick them all and 1 commandbox to untick them all

So far I have a working prototype, but I have 2 problems:
1) the checkboxes are not linked to the cells in column A, they are just positioned when I created them
2) the checkboxes are not dynamic, I created them manually and had to write an event handler (onclick) for each checkbox (> 50 checkboxes)

I have tried to create a code to dynamically add checkboxes and create a class module to handle the events, but I am really stuck..
I copied and modified some code that was originally intended for a userform and I managed to make it work on a userform, but I'd rather have everything on the worksheet as i described above.

Here is the class module code (named: clsBoxEvent)

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents cBox As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub cBox_Click()
MsgBox cBox.Name
End Sub
```

Here is the code I wrote as a module. I plan to put it in an event (onclick) from a command button which I plan to click to update the list of checkboxes. Unless this is not necessary as there is a way that the checkboxes are created as soon as the cell in column B isn't blank ?

I thank you for your input.

```
Dim chkBoxEvent As clsBoxEvent
Dim chkBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim chkBoxColl As Collection

Private Sub chkBox_update()
Dim i As Integer
Set chkBoxColl = New Collection

For i = 1 To 5
    ' I wrote the code just to add 5 checkboxes as a test. Later I will need to adapt this to the actual required number of checkboxes (the number of products in column B)  

    Set chkBox = Controls.Add("Forms.CheckBox.1", "ChkBox" & i)
    With chkBox
       ' I work with the position as I did not know how to link it to the cells in colums A
        .Left = 126
        .Height = 16
        .Top = 6 + ((i - 1) * 16)
    End With

Set chkBoxEvent = New clsBoxEvent
Set chkBoxEvent.cBox = Controls(chkBox.Name)
chkBoxColl.Add chkBoxEvent

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014421/how-to-add-events-to-controls-created-at-runtime-in-excel-with-vba). There are a few answers here that should help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My answer to: [Excel VBA script to insert multiple checkboxes linked to cell with yes and no instead of true and false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430745/excel-vba-script-to-insert-multiple-checkboxes-linked-to-cell-with-yes-and-no-in/39434543#39434543) seems like it will work nicely for you.

[image]

```
Sub AddCheckBoxes()

    Dim cb As CheckBox
    Dim myRange As Range, cel As Range
    Dim wks As Worksheet

    Set wks = Sheets("Sheet1")

    Set myRange = wks.Range("A1:A1000")

    For Each cel In myRange

        Set cb = wks.CheckBoxes.Add(cel.Left, cel.Top, 30, 6)

        With cb
            .Caption = ""
            .OnAction = "ProcessCheckBox"
        End With

    Next

End Sub

Sub ProcessCheckBox()
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set cb = .CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
        If Not cb Is Nothing Then cb.TopLeftCell = IIf(cb.Value = 1, "Cleared", "")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you!
The .OnAction was exactly what I needed :)

Btw while playing around I discovered a few things. Maybe you have some explanations ?
- I couldn't change the size of the box of the checkbox itself
- Depending on the height I defined for the checkbox (even though the height didn't change visually), if it exceeded the height of the row, it checked the checkbox below instead of the one I clicked
- I couldn't center the checkboxes horizontally in the cells just by using cell and checkbox width, but had to use a small correction factor
- The value when unchecked is -4146

Comment: I had the same issues with them.  Thanks for excepting my answer.  Sorry that I couldn't be more help.